# Who is the best cloud hosting provider for managing multiple sites with unique IP addresses/vhosts?

Tags: php, apache, hosting, cloud, virtualhost

Over the past few weeks I have been trying to scout out a viable alternative to my hybrid/dedicated box over at WiredTree. I have all but landed on a cloud server solution from either Amazon (EC2) or Rackspace (Cloud Servers). My questions are:

1) Between those two, and any other cloud provider I may have missed out there, who can offer me the best solution for hosting multiple sites. 
 a. This gets a little more complicated because in an ideal world, I would like to associate a unique ip address to each site that I deploy on the server. However, after reading about the cloud options out there, I realized that this may not be a viable option and I may have to settle for same IP on the same instance, but make use of Vhosts. Which brings me to:

2) Is there an easy way, within the cloud or otherwise, to dynamically add a vhost to my HOST file and Apache.conf file so that I can easily create a script within my admin back end which allows the creation these new sites.

The main issue here is scalability. If I can I would be able to scale this solution up to 50 sites if need be and it would be as easy as filling in an html form -> sending that form to php on the back end, and then having my new site configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

[Virtual Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) and Unique IPs contradict each others

> **Virtual hosting** is a method for
>   hosting multiple domain names on a
>   computer using a **single** IP address.

Comment: Hmmmm, according to Apache:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html

They do not contradict each other at all...

What your referring to is the typical/likely scenario for vhosts, but it's only one way of slicing the pie. It's what's considered name based virtual hosting.